# Sampling a tensor multiple times

Tags: pytorch

I am solving a problem that requires randomly sampling "b" rows from a 2d tensor "A" ,"M" times.

I was trying this code to create a 3d tensor

```
np.random.choice(len(A), size=(M, b))
```

This code is giving an error that too many indices for the tensor of dimension 2. I can write a code to get a 3d tensor but can I use broadcasting to achieve this faster

I tried `np.random.choice(len(A), size=(M, b)`) and it did not work

So I working with loops now using the following script.

```
samples= np.random.choice(len(A), size=(M, b))
G_tensor = torch.zeros((M,b,A.shape[1]))

for i in range(M):
    G_tensor[i] = A[samples[i]]
```

Comment: Which values of `A`, `M`, and `b` lead to an error? Please provide a minimal example. Running with `A = [1]*10`, `M=11`, and `b=4` will not throw an error on my end.

Comment: B=torch.tensor([[1,2,3,-1],[4,5,6,-2],[7,8,9,-3]])
B_sample = B[np.random.choice(len(B), size=(4, 2))]. I took M=4 and b=2 and got IndexError

Answer (score 0):

This is easily accomplishable with list indexing. Let `A` be a 2D tensor of size `[m,n]`:

```
[m,n] = A.shape
idx = torch.randint(m,(M*b,)) # yields array of size M*b in range [0,m]
G = A[idx,:] # G is of shape [M*b,n]

#reshape
G = G.view(M,b,-1)  # G is of shape [M,b,n]
```

Now, this does not guarantee no repeated rows within the `b` rows selected for each of `M` iterations. If you want this constraint we can slightly modify how we generate `idx`:

```
[m,n] = A.shape
r = torch.rand(M,m)    # random of shape[M,m]

#  each of M rows corresponds to a random permutation of the m rows
r_sort_idx = torch.argsort(r,dim = 1)   # shape [M,m], 

# get first b out of m rows for each of M
r_select = r_sort_idx[:,:b] # shape [M,b], 

# reshape for list indexing
idx = r_select.view(-1) # reshape into [M*b]

# perform indexing
G = A[idx,:]            # shape [M*b,n]
G = G.view(M,b,-1)      # shape [M,b,n]
```